# How to create switching views

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app with the following views and view transistions.

View 1 -> View 2 -> View 3 -> View 4

On the return it can go View 1 <- View 2 <- View 3 <- View 4
or                      View 1 <- View 2 <- View 4

Basically on view 4 you go either go view 3 or view 2.
When app closes either sleep or user left the app, it loads on view 1.

Issue I have, each view I put as its own view controller. And called by the following method.

```
    TableViewSelect *tableviewselect = [[TableViewSelect alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController: tableviewselect animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

This raised the issue, of the new view being displayed ontop of the old view and the old view and all memory in it not being deallocated.

I was told that I should have used uinavigationcontroller instead of view controllers. Is this correct? So in an ideal world how should I add the views? Only issue I want is all memory being deallocated (such as nsmutablearray) when leaving the view.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to have the previous controller be deallocated when you leave it, then neither your approach nor a navigation controller approach will accomplish that. One way to do it would be to change the root view controller of the window whenever you want to change controllers,

```
TableViewSelect *tableviewselect = [[TableViewSelect alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.view.window.rootViewController = tableviewselect;
```

Unless your controllers are using a lot of memory though, a navigation controller approach might be better. It gives you transitions (which the above way does not), and a navigation bar for easily going backwards.

Comment: reason i need it to be deallocated is the app is a database gui, each screen has a lot of nsmutable array. When i leave a view and return to it, its not deleting the original, loading another version of it. Im watching the memory usage of the app increase rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationController would be your best option in this case. UINavigationController has methods for pushing and popping views off of the navigation "stack" (look up stacks related to computer science if you aren't familiar with the term). Depending on what path the user wants to take through the views (they would interact through the UI), you can push/pop a certain number of views, like popping twice to "skip" over view 3.

When you are notified that the app is closing, (depending on your implementation and goals, this could be done through notifications or view cycle methods like viewWillUnload) you can call the UINavigationController method to pop all views off of the stack, thereby returning to your first view. Good luck!